# Why to use "return@" in Ktor Route.get function

Tags: kotlin, ktor

In the Ktor official tutorial I saw the following code:

```
get("{id?}") {
val id = call.parameters["id"] ?: return@get call.respondText(
    "Missing id",
    status = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
)
val customer =
    customerStorage.find { it.id == id } ?: return@get call.respondText(
        "No customer with id $id",
        status = HttpStatusCode.NotFound
    )
call.respond(customer)
```

}

I can't understand, what is the purpose of the labeled return "return@". In [Kotlin documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/returns.html) it is said that: "return by default returns from the nearest enclosing function or anonymous function". In the provided code, as I understand, the get function is the nearest enclosing function, so why add labeled return to "get"?

Answer (score 0):

it's because you return not from enclosing or anonymous function, but from lambda. Here you can see not declaration of `get` function but its invocation with lambda